# Backbone.js don't include model properties in view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a model in Backbone.js like the following model:

```
Attribute = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        label: '',
        values: {},
    },
});
```

With this view:

```
AttributeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'button',
    className: 'btn',
    initialize: function(attribute) {
        this.attribute = attribute;
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var template = _.template($("#attribute-template").html(), {attribute: this.attribute});    
        this.$el.html(template);
    },
});
```

HTML template:

```
<!----- attribute template ----->
<script type="text/template" id="attribute-template">
    <span class="attr">
        <%= attribute.get('label') %>
    </span>
    <span class="badge pull-right"></span>
</script>
```

And it produces this:

```
<button label="..." values="[object Object],[object Object],..." class="btn">...</button>
```

My question is why does backbonejs add the label and values attributes to the html template and how can I prevent this?

Comment: Backbone is not adding those attributes. You can verify that by simply searching the [source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) for "label" or "value"

Comment: @StephenThomas it is getting them from the model attributes. If I change 'values' to 'children' then that shows up instead in the dom element

Comment: I think it would have helped if you were showing where you initialized the view with by passing the model as a value instead of part of the options.

Answer (score 1):

You have poorly chosen the name *attributes* to hold your model (why you're storing your model in a custom property is also beyond me), as Backbone.View.attributes is a property which is meant to specify HTML attributes to add to the view's el (which is your `<button>` tag - http://backbonejs.org/#View-attributes.

Typically, you would associate a model with a view by specifying a new instance of it in the *model* property, like below  Then you can reference the model as `this.model` and if you need just the data, `this.model.toJSON()`:

```
AttributeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: new Attribute(),
    tagName: 'button',
    className: 'btn',
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var template = _.template($("#attribute-template").html(), this.model.toJSON());    
        this.$el.html(template);
    },
});
```

FYI, here is an example of the proper usage of the *attributes* property:

```
AttributeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: new Attribute(),
    tagName: 'button',
    className: 'btn',
    attributes: {
        'data-foobar': "I'm a custom data attribute"
    }
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var template = _.template($("#attribute-template").html(), this.model.toJSON());    
        this.$el.html(template);
    },
});
```

This would then generate:

```
<button data-foobar="I'm a custom data attribute" class="btn">...</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was definitely a problem but not the direct cause.

Comment: How do you figure it wasn't a direct cause?  I bet that if you changed _attributes_ to some other name such as _foobar_, you will see that those attributes no longer appear in your el.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and the attributes were still occurring. Only after I tried my solution (see below) did it stop.

Comment: Yes, you weren't specifying your model correctly.  I covered that.

Comment: This isn't the answer here.  Calling it this.attribute doesn't cause his problem.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was initializing the view incorrectly. I was passing in the model directly

```
var itemView = new ItemView(item)
```

instead I need to declare it as the model

```
var itemView = new ItemView({model: item})
```

Also didn't realize that attribute is a View property so I had to rename my model and views.